# Caliburn.Micro, HelloScreens-sample

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm trying to understand the `HelloScreens` sample that comes with `Caliburn.Micro`. The `ShellView.xaml` includes a `ContentControl` at the bottom. Can someone please explain the importance of this element? I have tried to comment it out without seeing any difference.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens.Shell.ShellView"
             xmlns:...>
    <Grid>
    <local:TiledBackground SourceUri="/Resources/Images/backgroundtexture.png" />
        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/backgroundshadow.png"
               Stretch="Fill" />

        <ct:DockPanel>
          <.../>
        </ct:DockPanel>

        <!--  Whats this one for?  --/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Dialogs" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

It's binded to the viewmodels `Dialogs`-property, which is an custom implementation of `IConductActiveItem`, but what is it used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a `ContentControl` with the same name as a view model property, Caliburn.Micro will find the corresponding view for that view model, inject the view into the `ContentControl`, and bind up the view model to the view.

In this case, the `Dialogs` property is an `IDialogManager` type as you say, which resolves to `DialogConductorViewModel` (a conductor type). So the `DialogConductorView` is injected into the content control.

This view displays the dialogs in the application, and if you look at the view, it also has a `ContentControl` which displays the current `ActiveItem`. This is typical of a Caliburn.Micro conductor.

```
<Controls:CustomTransitionControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Margin="8" />
```

Note that the `DialogConductorView` is always displayed over the content of the application in `ShellView`, but the `Grid` inside the `DialogConductorView` is only visible if the `ActiveItem` is not null.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ActiveItem, Mode=TwoWay, 
Converter={StaticResource nullToCollapsed}}"
```

Comment: Aha! I missed that one. I haven't looked at the dialogs in detail yet, but assumed they lived inside each workspace. So when I deleted the contentcontrol, and the switch between workspaces still worked, I started to believe that the dialogmanager had no mission at all...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: so here is the question..should window be used or this method ?

Comment: Either technique is valid, it depends if you want your dialog to be a modal window, or just as content overlaying the current window.